# How to place data on mysql to php array()

Tags: php, arrays

I have about 50 users in a database and I want to send them a newsletter.

```
$result = mysql_query("SELECT email FROM users") or die(mysql_error());  
$row = mysql_fetch_array( $result ); // had 50 emails
```

How do I put the `$row['email']` into the mail code below.

```
$m->setBcc(Array("email@email.com", "email2@email.com","email3@email.com"));
```

Let me know.

Comment: I hope this is not a product quality code you are writing.. sending newsletters via bcc will give you no possibility to track which mails were sent successfully(what are you doing, if your script timeout?).. use pear::Mail_Queue instead..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
$recipients = array();

while($row=mysql_fetch_array($result))
{
 $recipients[] = $row['email'];
}

$m->setBcc($recipients);
```

tell me if it doesn't work and I'll immediately delete it :)